# how to implement a search using ajax in angular?

Tags: angular

I am using the website "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/" to make fake ajax calls.
I want to perform a search on my browser page.
I have defined a onSearch() which should receive the value of the input field(SearchText) and do a service call to fetch all the data from the url and then perform a comparison and output the matched data.
How can I do it?

My project.html :

My project.ts: as of now i havent implemented the logic for comparison need help on that as well.

```
onSearch(event){
    console.log(event.target.value)
```

The service to fetch data project.service.ts:

```
searchUsers(searchby:string,searchText:string):Observable<Posts[]>
  {
    return this.httpclient.get<Posts[]>('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
  }
```

Pls help.Thanks in advance.

Comment: What would be the comparison? Can you create a Stackblitz example?

Comment: the comparison will be between ids .Whatever id i enter in input should match with the corresponding id(from the data that has been fetched from URL).And then display corresponding record on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

```
searchField: FormControl;
form: FormGroup;
post : Post[] = []

constructor(private projectService ProjectService , private fb:FormBuilder){
    this.searchField = new FormControl();
    this.form = fb.group({search: this.searchField});

    this.searchField.valueChanges
      .debounceTime(400)
        .switchMap(term => this.projectService.searchUsers(term))
        .subscribe((resp) => {
            this.posts = resp.filter( // filter logic here)
        });
}
```

in html part you can use *ngFor structural directive to  display the list of items.